# int16 is not supported in a windows presentation foundation project wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why am I getting the following error: "Int16 is not supported in a windows presentation foundation project wpf."

I was reading the following MSDN text: 
[MSDN TEXT regrading primitives mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002(v=vs.110).aspx#xaml_2009_language_primitives)

Below is my simple code:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Int16 x:Key="cnst">12</x:Int16>        
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Why doesn't this code work? And what needs to be done to get it working.
My guess: `2006` needs to be replaced with `2009` for some future version.

Answer (score 7):

Basic types like `Int16` are defined in the `System` namespace (in the assembly mscorlib.dll), which is not mapped to the `x` XAML namespace.

Although XAML 2009 maps these types to the `x` namespace, you can't directly use them in your MainWindow's XAML, because (according to the [WPF Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002.aspx#wpf_support) paragraph in the XAML 2009 Language Features MSDN page)

> In WPF, you can use XAML 2009 features but only for XAML that is not
>   markup-compiled. Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the BAML form of
>   XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and features.

You may hence only add another XAML namespace that maps the `System` CLR namespace like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        ...>

    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Int16 x:Key="cnst">12</sys:Int16>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

Please also see the [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) article on MSDN for more details.

Comment: I know your current approach. But I was curious about MSDN paragraph. So, XAML 2009 is not launched yet ? And presently are we using XAML 2006 as reflected in <Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        ...> Also, do we need for XAML 2009 to be launched in future to use this syntax ?

Comment: It is already launched, but can still not be used in compiled XAML. From the article: *A scenario where you can use XAML 2009 features together with WPF is if you author loose XAML and you then load that XAML into a WPF runtime and object graph with XamlReader.Load. The WPF System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader and its Load can process XAML 2009 language keywords and features into a valid object graph representation.*